# How to configure Spacemacs to use the global installed intero?

Tags: haskell, emacs, spacemacs, haskell-mode, intero

Whenever I create a new project and I open it with Spacemacs, Spacemacs will try to install a local intero over and over again leaving me waiting for it to finish the installation. Can I just use my global installed intero for all my stack projects?

Comment: Note that it is not recommended to use a single installation for all your projects. Quoting [the docs](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/intero/blob/3f9cfc452faffbdb5c23c110ce0d0c7b099bc6c9/TOOLING.md): "Use `stack build` (not `install`) for each of your package sets. Each LTS or nightly should have a separate `stack build`. **If you use `stack install` you will run into incompatibility issues between package sets**."